# Knockout text on YouTube video

Tags: html, css

I want to create a knockout text effect using a YouTube video as the background video. I'm not able to achieve this, can anyone help me? Is it possible to set the video on the CSS side?

```css
.backdrop{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.video-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.text{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop">
<iframe class="video-backdrop" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&mute=1"></iframe>
<h1 class="text">Demo</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This link<https://css-tricks.com/css-techniques-and-effects-for-knockout-text/> will help you out

Comment: I've followed that guide for the codebase, but I need to use a video instead of the image

Comment: You probably need to add a video div behind the knockout text. Make sure the youtube video is working because the link didn't work for me.

Comment: the link I used to post the code is without the video id!

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of examples in the internet.
I've done a simple example inspired on the GeorgePark pen that you can find in here: https://codepen.io/GeorgePark/pen/LBPJGV

The secret is to add the text on top of the video with the property `mix-blend-mode: multiply;`, the element is multiplied by the background and replaces the background color. The resulting color is always as dark as the background. Since our text is white (#fff), the result will be the video below it.

Here is a simple version that you can found in here: https://codepen.io/diogoperes/pen/abzdYox

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* Video */

.video-background {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519373344801-14c1f9539c9c?w=1920&h=1080&fit=crop&crop=bottom) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground {
   height: 300%;
   top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground {
   width: 300%;
   left: -100%;
  }
}

/* Knockout Text */

.knockout-text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    font-size: calc(10px + 11vw + 2.5vh);
 font-weight: 900;
 letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    margin: auto;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #9f9f9f;
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.015em; 
}

.dark-theme .knockout-text {
 background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<body class="dark-theme">
    <div class="video-background">
        <div class="video-foreground">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bog4VzMWP20?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1&playlist=bog4VzMWP20" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen tabindex="-1"></iframe>
            <h1 class="knockout-text">KNOCKOUT</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: nice solution, I will play with the code to avoid using too many divs. Thanks for the help